# VSCode Saving 'filename.php' running 'PHP Intelephense' Formatter

Tags: visual-studio-code

I know this isn't a coding issue but it is an issue with VS code that I can't seem to figure out. Every time I save a file its coming up with this message and doesn't complete or save the file until I press cancel.

```
Saving 'filename.php' running 'PHP Intelephense' Formatter
```

I then click configure and it takes me to the format on save setting, if I disable format on save it saves like normal again but without format on save... I've tried reinstalling beautify but that's not working and I'm just confused and stuck now...

Comment: Hey @VSLover333 how did you fix this? found any solution yet?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Saving '\*.php/\*.vue': Running 'PHP Intelephense/Vetur' Formatter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64053355/saving-php-vue-running-php-intelephense-vetur-formatter)