# Saving '*.php/*.vue': Running 'PHP Intelephense/Vetur' Formatter

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

I am having a bit problem on my VSCode. Everytime I save something, it just keeps loading.
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/03rHJ.png)

I am not sure why. Everything was fine last week ago. And I can't even type anything on my terminal.

I have this extensions installed.
[List 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IGodi.png)
[List 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/It0VG.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue since about a week. I notice your PHP Intelephense extension is also on v1.5.4.

I changed the extension to an older version (1.5.3), this solved the issue for me. I created an issue on the github page of the PHP Intelephense extension.

[Screenshot for changing the extension version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uCodQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

maybe this is related, but I am running with the same issue here as well, on a Mint 21 machine.

I realized that PHP Intelephense needed an update, once I ran that, the saving was normal.